# How to find if a word immediately followed by a non-letter character exists in a String

Tags: java, regex

I believe the most efficient solution to this issue is to use Regex but I'm uncertain of the syntax. When looking through a sentence, how do you identify if a word followed by a non-letter character (anything other than a,b,c,d,e...) is present in a string. Example below:

```
String word = "eat"

String sentence = "I like to eat!"
This satisfies the condition because the exclamation point is not a letter

String sentence = "I like to beat!"
This does not satisfy the condition because beat is not eat. This is also an application where the contains() method fails

String sentence = "I like to eats"
This does not satisfy the condition because eat is followed by a letter
```

Comment: Does *end of input* count - ie should `"I like to eat"` match?

Comment: @Bohemian yes that counts as a match as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *word boundary* regex `\b`, which matches *between* a letter and a non-letter (or visa versa):

```
str.matches(".*\\b" + word + "\\b.*")
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/rISPBab58j2o9s).

Although numbers are also considered "word characters", this should work for you.

I've used a word boundary are the start too so "I want to beat" does not match.

Comment: Note: The currently accepted answer does not work for  `"I like to eat"`.

Comment: I was thinking about that too.  And what about "I like to eat meat!"  And the OP wasn't clear about spaces following the word either.

Comment: The following code results in ```false```. Am I doing something wrong?  ```String str = "I like to eat";
  String word= "eat";
  
  boolean matcher = str.matches(".*\b" + word + "\b.*");
  
  System.out.println(matcher);```

Comment: @FinDev my bad: you must use double backslash. String literal `\b` in java is a backspace character. To specify the regex `\b` you must use `"\\b"`

Comment: @Bohemian awesome thank you so much, this works great and is very simple

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
sentence.matches(".*\\b" + word + "[^a-zA-Z\\s].*");
```

If you want "I like to eat" to also match, you can use:

```
sentence.matches(".*\\b" + word + "([^a-zA-Z\\s]|$).*");
```

Comment: I would think that this would match "beat", and so failing case 2.

Comment: @jdaz how would you alter this in the event that there is a space after eat. For example if eat is in the middle of a sentence " I like to eat every day", the correction doesnt seem to work